Color mismatch between a triplot and a linecollection in the same figure
I am plotting a triangle mesh with vertex colors given by the x-coordinate of each vertex, along with a collection of line segments with colors given by the x-coordinate of each midpoint.  The triangle mesh in question is an "angle bracket shape with a circular cut-away" and the line segments are the boundary of the circular cut-away.  I get the following image:

Note the  color mismatch between the line segment collection and the triangles in the triangle mesh immediately adjacent to it.  The image is generated by this pseudocode
plt.figure()
T = Triangulation(bracket_vertices[:,0], bracket_vertices[:,1], bracket_triangles)
c = plt.tripcolor(T, bracket_vertices[:,0])

line_collection = LineCollection(circle_vertices[circle_segments,:], circle_midpoints[:,0])
plt.gca().add_collection(line_collection)

plt.colorbar(mappable=c)
plt.show()

where
bracket_vertices is an array of size nbverts x 2
bracket_triangles is an array of size nbtris x 3 of indices referencing into the above
circle_vertices is an array of size ncverts x 2
circle_segments is an array of size ncsegs x 2 of indices referencing into the above
circle_midpoints is an array of size ncsegs x 2
I feel that the color mismatch that I'm seeing in this image is a bit too big.  My question is: is this color-mismatch an artifact of the way matplotlib assigns colors, or am I mis-using the color specifications in some way?  I hope the above pseudocode is sufficiently clear to debug the issue, at least conceptually.  Thanks very much for your help.

By default the full colour range is used for each individual collection.  You can pass the norm parameter to both tripcolor and LineCollection to specify a different mapping from data to colour https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormapnorms.html#colormapnorms

Problem solved!  Thank you.
